# Getting black blank image when extracting a thumbnail from a video

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a thumbnail image from a video from a URL using AVFoundation but I am getting a black blank image as attached.

The video URL is https://www.riptide.tv/app/assets/2/3/small_3001190658061_2.mp4

Below is my code:

```
func videoSnapshot(videoURL: String, imgName : String) -> UIImage? {

        let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
        let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(1), preferredTimescale: 100)
        do {
            let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
            downloadedThumbnails.updateValue(thumbnail, forKey: imgName)
            return thumbnail
        } catch {
            return UIImage(named: imgName)
        }
}
```

[black img extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmpQl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code to

```
func videoSnapshot(videoURL: String, imgName : String) -> UIImage? {

    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(5), preferredTimescale: 100)
    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
        return thumbnail
    } catch {
        return UIImage(named: imgName)
    }
}
```

thats 5 seconds in. You can see the thumbnail generated.

[image: Thumbnail]

This is because `AVAssetImageGenerator` is pretty flexible in what times it gets its frames

```
func videoSnapshot(videoURL: String, imgName : String) -> UIImage? {

    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(1), preferredTimescale: 100)
    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
        return thumbnail
    } catch {
        return UIImage(named: imgName)
    }
}
```

Setting

```
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
```

ensures you get a frame accurate thumbnail.

For more info see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1390571-requestedtimetolerancebefore

Comment: Thank you @JackWilkinson! That was exactly the issue, changed the seconds to 8 and got a perfect thumbnail.

Comment: The settings you've suggested are also useful, added those and changed the second to 1